# Plotly's interactive charts in PyCharm's SciView

Tags: python, charts, pycharm, plotly, interactive

PyCharm's SciView is by default able to show only static charts.

A plugin however exists, called [lets-plot](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14379-lets-plot-in-sciview), allowing it to display interactive charts. Unfortunately this works by default with the python homonymous library [lets-plot](https://github.com/JetBrains/lets-plot).

Nonetheless, the very fact that the plugin is able to display interactive charts would make me believe there must be a way to direct plotly's output to that renderer. What I can see available in plotly (`plotly.io.renderers`) are:

```
Default renderer: 'browser'
    Available renderers:
        ['plotly_mimetype', 'jupyterlab', 'nteract', 'vscode',
         'notebook', 'notebook_connected', 'kaggle', 'azure', 'colab',
         'json', 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'svg', 'pdf', 'browser',
         'firefox', 'chrome', 'chromium', 'iframe', 'iframe_connected',
         'sphinx_gallery']
```

**Question**: does anyone know if this issue can somehow be circumvented allowing to display plotly's output in the embedded sciview?

**What am I not looking for**: I am aware of the alternatives, including rendering in browser, and rendering in jupyter notebooks.

Answer (score 1):

No, at the moment there is no way of displaying HTML/JS interactive chart in PyCharm' SciView.

Lets-plot among others also supports Java Swing frontend (see: [Lets-Plot in JVM and Kotlin/JS application](https://github.com/JetBrains/lets-plot-kotlin#jvm)). This is what make its interactive charts possible in PyCharm.

Comment: Isn't there any way to redirect plotly charts to Lets-plot 's renderer? Otherwise, I can see plotly's interactive charts work perfectly in an embedded viewer in Pycharm, but only if run in the R-plugin for pycharm (that is from an R script). This seems to suggest it is tehnically feasible - is it not possible to redirect the output of plotly as run from python onto the pycharm r-plugin viewer?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to render Plotly charts with lets-plot. Ideally SciView should support interactive html/js output but at the moment it doesn't. Check out this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29311